# MySQL Count Two Tables with Dateranges

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with each of table having their same ID from the first time of Member Join.

Once the member has been Approved, he/she will be Rejected also for a some reason and condition.

The Query Result needs to sort by date ranges then counting total approves and total rejects based on each date from chosen ID.

**In this case, I've selected for join_id 325.**

Table approves:

```
join_id         approved_date
325             2016-03-20
326             2016-03-20
326             2016-03-20
325             2016-03-21
326             2016-03-21
325             2016-03-21
325             2016-03-21
327             2016-03-21
325             2016-03-22
327             2016-03-22
325             2016-03-22
```

Table rejects:

```
join_id         rejected_date
325             2016-03-20
325             2016-03-20
326             2016-03-20
325             2016-03-21
327             2016-03-21
325             2016-03-22
327             2016-03-22
325             2016-03-22
```

This is I've tried:

```
SELECT
approved_date,
COUNT(join_id) AS join_id
FROM approves
WHERE join_id = 325
AND approved_date BETWEEN '2016-03-19' AND '2016-03-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(approved_date, '%Y-%m-%d');

SELECT
rejected_date,
COUNT(join_id) AS join_id
FROM rejects
WHERE join_id = 325
AND rejected_date BETWEEN '2016-03-19' AND '2016-03-26' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(rejected_date, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Results for join_id **325** I expected:

```
date_time|approves|rejected
2016-03-19|0|0
2016-03-20|1|2
2016-03-21|3|1
2016-03-22|2|2
2016-03-23|0|0
2016-03-24|0|0
2016-03-25|0|0
2016-03-26|0|0
```

Comment: let us know ..what you have tried

Comment: @Jordan I've put the code I just tried. Please review.

Answer (score 1):

```
select events.join_id, events.date, sum(approve) as approves, sum(reject) as rejects
    from (
        select join_id, approved_date as date, 1 as approve, 0 as reject from approves 
        union
        select join_id, rejected_date as date, 0 as approve, 1 as reject from rejects
    ) as events
    group by events.join_id, events.date
where events.join_id = ? -- Here you can have more complex condition
```

May not be very optimal but simplest I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this too

```
select t1.join_id, t1.counting as approved, t2.counting as rejected from
(
select join_id, count(*) as counting from approves group by join_id
) as t1 inner join 
(
select join_id, count(*) as counting from rejects group by join_id
) as t2 on t1.join_id=t2.join_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT d, 
       COALESCE(approved_count, 0) AS approved_count, 
       COALESCE(rejected_count, 0) AS rejected_count
FROM ( 
  SELECT DISTINCT approved_date AS d
  FROM approves

  UNION 

  SELECT DISTINCT rejected_date
  FROM rejects) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT approved_date, COUNT(*) AS approved_count
   FROM approves
   GROUP BY approved_date
) AS t2 ON t1.d = t2.approved_date
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT rejected_date, COUNT(*) AS rejected_count
   FROM rejects
   GROUP BY rejected_date
) AS t3 ON t1.d = t3.rejected_date
ORDER BY d
```

Comment: this is more closely I think. But still not resulted as I guess. But Thank you.